# independent and separate Virtual Desktops on each Monitor - Win 10 & 11

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-11, virtual-desktop, multitasking

I know it is not a new problem, but I'm switching from MAC to Win and this issue drastically affected my productivity.

the problem was discussed in multiple forums without any clear answer, but I'm determined to find a workaround for it with your help.

The issue is simple, I want to have an individual Virtual Desktop on each monitor (I'm using two external monitors) and I want them to be independent (e.g. when I change the [Virtual] Desktop on monitor 1 by three-finger sweep to left/right, I want the Desktop on Monitor 2 to remain still and independent from the actions being done on monitor 1, similar to Mac).

I know some people suggested using third-party tools, I tried some of them (e.g. Actual Desktops from ActualTools) but they are very far from being efficient and practical.

Also, I came across some threads from the past that such a feature was implemented on Windows 10 version 21H2 onward: A new toggle switch is now hidden in "Settings>System>Multitasking>Displays Have Separate Virtual Desktops"

I tried to install windows 10 and explore this option, but this feature was not there!

So, Now I'm asking for your help.

if you are using Windows 10 (whatever version) and have this feature enabled or have the above option visible in your settings, then a record of your relevant "registry keys" can be a clue to fix this problem for me (I'm using Win11). Based on my experience and development background, if the feature was there once upon a time, then possibly with some registry changes and tweaks it can be activated again.

Else, if you know a workaround, then let me know.

Comment: I had the same problem, although not coming from a mac. For me after going through all options, and yes, I am an ActualTools user, it works, but has its quircks. I went a different approach. It is always one set of programs that I want to switch between as if they are on different desktops, but it is not like several apps are grouped together. Eg, when I am on destkop Y, I need app1, app2 and app3. Its always just one app for me. So what I done is get TidyTabs. (I have also used Groupy with similar results). Each app gets a tab, and you can make a tab group. Switching between tabs hides others

Answer (score 6):

The feature of "Displays Have Separate Virtual Desktops" was
[announced](https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/02/23/windows-10-is-getting-new-multitasking-features-with-sun-valley-update/)
in 2021, when it was detected in the test Insider builds of Windows 10.

However, it apparently was not stable enough, so didn't make it for
the Windows 10 22H1 release or even 22H2. Nor was it released with
Windows 11 in any of its 2022 releases.

The actual status of this feature is currently unknown. It was demanded
in many feature requests and posts in the Microsoft forums, but we
do not currently know if Microsoft is still working on it.

You will need to adapt yourself to another mode of work.
Perhaps the option of "Show this window on all desktops" will be helpful.

The product
[Actual Virtual Desktops](https://www.actualtools.com/virtualdesktops/)
($19.95) has its own implementation for this option.
If interested, see the article
[Independent Virtual Desktops on Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/virtualdesktops/independent_virtual_desktops_on_multiple_monitors.shtml).

Comment: OP mentions they have used ActualTools's solution, and that it was not what they wanted. I am an ActualTools user myself, and I can say, it works, but it has its quirks. Enough for me to completely abandon the virtual desktop approach altogether and switch to a tabbed approach instead. I now use TinyTabs and put all my programs in one tabgroup, and its like having a tiny virtual desktop. Works pretty well.

Comment: Wow, don't sleep on the "Show this window on all desktops" option. It's not exactly what the user asked for, but depending on the use case it may be very close. I needed to keep Chat and Git pinned on a side monitor, regardless of the active virtual desktop, and  now I can! Thanks for bringing this up

Answer (score 6):

The workaround I found that is somehow satisfying for me is by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then right clicking the window you want to stay on my extended monitor and then select `Show this on all desktops`

Comment: Where exactly is the option "Show this on all desktops"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ramhound - Win + Tab then right click the desired program

Comment: @tjb1 - Your answer indicates ALT+TAB

Comment: @Ramhound - I did not post the answer.

Comment: @tjb1 - My aplogizes.  In that case this answer is partially incorrect and should be edited by it's author.

Comment: @user1798032 - This answer mentions the incorrect keyboard shortcut.  You should [edit] it so it references the correct shortcut.